# postgres query for overlapping integer time intervals

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a postgres table of the form

```
from_secs, to_secs, value
       10       20      1
       12       50      2
       
              ....
```

now at query time I get a list of time intervals `[(from_secs1, to_secs1), (from_secs2, to_secs2), ...]` and I need to get all the values which `(from_secs, to_secs)` overlap with at least 1 of the interval in the list.

How can I do that?

**EXAMPLE:**

Taking as example the above table and an input list of `[(1, 11), (55, 100)]`

Then the query should return the first row of the table as it is the only one that overlap with at least 1 interval of the list

Comment: Update your post with sample input data and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an [integer range](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) built from the `from_secs, to_secs` combination and compare that to a multirange.

Then use the [overlaps operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html)

```
select *
from the_table
where int4range(from_secs, to_secs, '[]') && int4multirange(int4range(1, 11,'[]'), int4range(55, 100,'[]'));
```

The ranges are all created as "inclusive" on both edges.

Comment: this looks a good answer but I am getting an error: ` function int4multirange(int4range, int4range) does not exist` I do not understand why. I am calling from python

Comment: @Donbeo: you need at least Postgres 14 for that.